# Spreading Activation Theory

Tags: cognitive-psychology, memory

Two questions, (im trying to get my head around this area of study, my assignment is on neurophysiological differences of t/f memory not theories, but reading up on the topic has had me thinking and I can't seem to find answers...)

1. What is the difference between the implicit associative response account (Underwood 1965) and the Spreading Activation Theory (Collins & Loftus)
2. Evidence by (McDermott & Watson 2001 and others) shows that repeated presentation improves both true and false memory, but once exposure to the list words is excessive it only boosts true memory. Which seems to me to not be consistent with the spreading activation theory which posits that the more associative activation is accrued, the stronger the false memory should be. Can anyone think of how to explain the data under the Spreading Activation Theory? I found another theory (spreading activation/monitoring that would explain it but was just hoping to see if anyone could preserve the spreading activation theory alone)

Comment: There is no harm in asking two separate questions. Perhaps you should split this question into two? (You can always edit this one, and pose a new one.)

Comment: Agreed. This is too broad to answer as written, but mostly because these are actually two independent good questions.